# How to handle exception twice

Tags: error-handling, typescript, angular

I have extended the ExceptionHandler class:

```
import {Injectable, ExceptionHandler} from '@angular/core';

export class FirstError extends Error {
    handle() {
        console.log("This is firstError handler");
    }
}

export class AnotherError extends Error {
    handle() {
        console.log("This is AnotherError handler");
    }
}

export class _ArrayLogger {
    res = [];
    log(s: any): void { this.res.push(s); }
    logError(s: any): void { this.res.push(s); }
    logGroup(s: any): void { this.res.push(s); }
    logGroupEnd() {};
}

@Injectable()
export class CustomExceptionHandler extends ExceptionHandler {
    constructor() {
        super (new _ArrayLogger(), true);
    }

    call(exception: any, stackTrace = null, reason = null) {
        // I want to have original handler log exceptions to console
        super.call(exception, stackTrace, reason);

        // If exception is my type I want to do some additional actions
        if (exception.originalException instanceof Error) {
            exception.originalException.handle();
        }
    }
}
```

My goal is to have super.call log the error to the console as original Angular2 ExceptionHandler, and additionally do my own exception handle. Unfortunately, in such a scenario super gets called only the first time the error is thrown. When the second, third .. occurs, the super is not get called. How to make it work so the original console.log logs the error to console, and additionaly error processing is also done?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but was able to get it working by passing `false` in the constructor for the second parameter (rethrowException).

```
constructor() {
    super (new _ArrayLogger(), false);
}
```

The name of the parameter would suggest that the correct value is indeed `true`; seems a bit backward to me but it works.